# Show custom post status when logged out

Tags: custom-post-types, posts, 404-error, post-status

**Background**:
I have a few different custom post status on my installation. We use them for a workflow.

Lets just say for example we have:
Draft (built in)
ForClient (custom)
Published (built in)

Now for example you go to view the custom post type, using the custom post status on the single post page:
/?p=number&post_type=project&preview=true

When you're logged in, you can see it no problem, no matter the status.

**Currently**:
When you're logged out, Wordpress will send you to the themes 404 page. The only way to stop this is to fully Publish it.

**Question**:
I would like a custom post status (not all of them, just this one) to not 404 redirect. It should just show the page as usual.
Can I do this with a hook/filter? Do I have to hack the core if I wanted this?

Comment: I was able to edit class-wp-querry (around line 3064 and line 3071). This is obviously not ideal, any thoughts so I don't have to build in a stupid amount of custom logic into here? https://i.imgur.com/e5DBAei.png

Comment: `&post_type=ForClient` ? I thought `ForClient` is a post status?

Comment: @SallyCJ oops! I will edit my first post

Comment: Not allowing the public to see un-published posts/ post-previews is a part of core, but this plugin can get you around that with specific links for previews, maybe that will help? https://wordpress.org/plugins/public-post-preview/